# IntelliJ: Spring MVC beans in JSP pages are not resolved

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

When I put something in model in spring mvc like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("item", new Item());
    return "item/new";
}
```

bean "item" is not resolved by IntelliJ in corresponding JSP pages. I mean, it works perfectly fine, but autocompletion doesn't :/

Is there any way to have autocompletion in such case?

Comment: I wonder whether such a feature can be provided by the Development Environment tools. In jsp it can do autocompletion of the jsp tags and html's but how can it autocomplete a bean which is totally out of scope for that jsp. All those will be tied up together during runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IntelliJ's JSP support understands a special kind of comment annotation:

```
<%--@elvariable id="foo" type="com.yourcompany.YourClass"--%>
```

If you place this annotation at the top of your file, idea will provide auto completion for expressions starting with `${foo.` based on the properties of class `com.yourcompany.YourClass`

IntelliJ will also offer to create this annotation if you hover over the `foo` part of an expression.

Comment: Patrick Flyod - Really cool to know such a thing is there. Is there anything similar there in Eclipse as well. Just curious to know.

Comment: @raddykrish not that I know of. perhaps in myeclipse